# Pass props to components react-router 1.0.x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router 1.0.2. I have a component Catalog representing a catalog of products, I don't want to write a different Catalog for each different product but to reuse the existing one and to pass the productType as prop from the router. How am I supposed to do it with this version of react-router? So far I have tried this without sucess... Thank you

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home}/>

            <Route path="phones" component={Catalog} productType="phones"/>
            <Route path="about" component={About}/>
            <Route path="login" component={Login}/>

        </Route>
    </Router>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('main')
```

);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leave your routes as generic as possible, which is what I think you're trying to achieve.  To do this, you could look at the current path from within your `Catalog` component and depending on what it is, render a different child element.  Suppose you have a `Product` component, you could pass the product type to that.

So if you had route:

```
<Route path="catalog/:productType" component={Catalog}/>
```

You could do this:

```
class Catalog extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let productType = this.props.params.productType;

        return (
            <div className="catalog">
                <Product type={productType}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, so you are suggesting to pass it as url param instead of a prop. Elegant. I like it. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help :)